# how to keep border height 50%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

want to give border on two div but full height is not looking good. i want to keep it 50%. how can i do that?

```
<div class="border-right">

    <h4>>Web Design</h4>

    <p>Morbi ac molestie justo. Donec sagittis scelerisque enim a tempus. Integer eget purus est. Phasellus consectetur sodales enim, eu dapibus metus mollis a. Phasellus luctus nulla in eros vestibulum mattis. Mauris pellentesque sem quis tortor vestibulum lacinia. Suspendisse hendrerit enim id pulvinar euismod. Etiam et neque vitae justo dignissim laoreet sit amet eget metus. Ut tristique porttitor lorem vitae auctor. </p>

</div>

<div class="border-left">

    <h4>>Web Design</h4>

    <p>Morbi ac molestie justo. Donec sagittis scelerisque enim a tempus. Integer eget purus est. Phasellus consectetur sodales enim, eu dapibus metus mollis a. Phasellus luctus nulla in eros vestibulum mattis. Mauris pellentesque sem quis tortor vestibulum lacinia. Suspendisse hendrerit enim id pulvinar euismod. Etiam et neque vitae justo dignissim laoreet sit amet eget metus. Ut tristique porttitor lorem vitae auctor. </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with css or create Js Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Border can't be set to 50% of element total height. But you can use ::after & ::before to draw some lines on sides

```css
body{
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
div{
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
div::before{
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
div::after{
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.all-border{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.all-border::before,
.all-border::after{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>50% Height Border</div>
<div class="all-border">100% Height Border</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some css. Change `<div class="border-right">` to `<div class="border-right" style="max-height:50%;">`.
Comment if this is not what you are looking for.